# How to do Flexbox's justify space-around in pure css

Tags: css, flexbox

How to equally space divs, not only between each other like justify, but also on the sides to the container.

I would like to recreate flexbox's "justified" + "space-around" and "wrap" feature in pure/regular css.

shown here (use handle to shrink):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="flex-container resize">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </div>

  <p>A container with the justify-content property set to <em>space-around</em> will display its items with the equal amount of space around them.</p>

</body>
```

My closest attempt can be found here:
Problems: no equal spacing at the sides to the container. (use handle to shrink):

```css
.my-nonflex-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  text-align: justify;
}

.spacer {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}

.my-nonflex-container>div {
  background-color: #faffff;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.stretch {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #003060;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="my-nonflex-container resize">
    <div class="spacer">
      <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
      <div>5</div>
    </div>
    <span class="stretch">stretcher workaround</span>
  </div>



  </div>

  <p>A container with the text-justify property and a span-stretch to also justify "wrapped" content.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: add padding to container

Comment: Im afraid, padding wouldn't be dynamically the same size as the space between the divs. Also when only one item is wrapped to the next line, it should be centered.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do. Are you trying to mimic flexbox behaviour on non-flexbox compliant browsers?

Comment: The reason is to have a better understanding of html/css.
But it appears that it is not possible, and that flexbox not only makes life simpler but actually adds features otherwise not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to somewhat replicate flex properties with non flex CSS but I am not sure you will be able to get everything you want with just CSS.

I managed a somewhat replica of `justify-content: space-around` with the following CSS:

```
<div class="not-a-flexbox">
  <div class="box">
    <p> 1 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p> 2 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p> 3 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p> 4 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p> 5 </p>
  </div>
</div>

.not-a-flexbox {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;

}

.box > p {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 60px;
    min-height: 60px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

See it in action here: **https://jsfiddle.net/kz60gnjw/**

Unfortuantely I couldnt get this to wrap.

Although it isnt quite what you asked I did manage to get a non flexbox replica of `justify-content: space-between` to work and to wrap. You can see the code for that here: **https://jsfiddle.net/g1kvcn7z/**

---

My answer was mainly based on this article: https://kyusuf.com/post/almost-complete-guide-to-flexbox-without-flexbox

I had trouble combining the different parts of flexbox in the manner you want but you may be able to find something I missed. Just in case it helps there are some more examples of flexbox styles being replicated without flexbox here: **https://codepen.io/msankhala/pen/PNawBK**

At the end of the day I think you may have to resort to using media queries to change the layout when it comes to wrapping properly (which sort of defeats the point). Your other alternative would of course be javaScript but I didnt suggest that as you ruled it out in your title.

If this is for use as a fallback for something that doesnt support flexbox then I found this article: **https://medium.com/css-mine/flexbox-how-to-deal-with-older-browsers-fbf6eb8c7a65**

### I hope some of this helped. Good luck